# How to Notify When The Time is over by thread in background android

Tags: java, android

i want to check that from my app when the user choose to talk with admin for specific time,then i want to restrict that user to talk with the specified time and notify a warning messeage when it stops. it sholud work like for eg:- the data pack notifies the user when the validiy on data is over. int

Comment: you have to use service and other is alarm manager to notification for alert

Answer (score 0):

try this code to notify,....

```
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```